# can i call a child form base class method from the mdi parent class

Tags: vb.net

i am trying to populate a dropdown selection in a child form from a form in the MDI parent. this dropdown is taken from the childs base class. it is basically a rolodex of the data that populates the dropdown on the child only with additional info to make it easier for the user.

My Code:

```
Public Sub mnufileitem9_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnufileitem9.Click

    If Not ActiveMdiChild Is Nothing Then
        Dim frm As Object
        frm = Me.ActiveMdiChild
        Dim KeyField As String = frm.KeyField
        Dim NameField As String = frm.NameField
        If frm.TableName <> "" Then
            frm.Invoke(New InvokeOpenRolodex(AddressOf frm.frmBaseFM.OpenRolodex))
            Dim r As New ABLM.frmRolodex(frm.TableName, frmLogin.sConn)
            Try
                If r.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
                    mSelectedItem = r.Result(KeyField)
                    ChangingTextOnly = True
                    frmBaseFM.ToolStrip_txtKey.SelectedText = SelectedItem
                    ChangingTextOnly = False
                    frmBaseFM.ToolStrip_txtKey.Text = mSelectedItem

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                ABLM.LUCAS.Global.Utils.HandleError(ex, Me.Name & ".OpenRolodex")
            End Try
            r.Dispose()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("TableName property of frmBaseFM has not be coded. No Rolodex can be displayed", "Developer TODO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: it runs without error then nothing happens

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the first If statement, and single step through the code.

Comment: i have done that still no errors but what i do see is it looks like nothing is getting placed in frmBaseFM.ToolStrip_txtKey like i would expect.